# How to use dagger when depending on gradle library module used to share code?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

I am switching a project to dagger. **Project consists of :app gradle module and :library gradle module.** Library is not a real library in a sense, but a way to share code common code between variations of app.

*So basically it provides for example BaseFooFragment to be extended by :app module via FooFragment.* More concrete example would be BaseRestManager which is used all over library. App should extend it to RestManager. Also it should be a singleton.

What I would normally do without dagger is have BaseApp application class in :library module provide BaseRestManager and use that inside library. In app module I would subclass the BaseApp to App and override the BaseRestManager , provide the RestClient and narrow the return type from BaseRestManager getRestManager to RestManager getRestManager, so also consuming App code doesnt have to cast it.

Btw library module will always be module, its not needed for it to work on its own. Its just a way to share code. DRY.

**How would I do this in dagger? If I have a @Provides method returning BaseRestManager and second @Provides returning RestManager both annotated @Singleton, it obviously creates 2 instances which is not what I want. It should only be one, instance of RestManager.**

```
public abstract class BaseApp extends Application {
    public abstract BaseRestManager getRestManager();
}

public class App extends BaseApp {

    private RestManager mRestManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mRestManager = new RestManager(...);
    }

    @Override public RestManager getRestManager() {
        return mRestManager;
    }
}

public class BaseFooFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Default", "BaseFooFragment # baseRestManager=" + ((BaseApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getRestManager());
    }
}

public class FooFragment extends BaseFooFragment {

    @Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Default", "FooFragment # restManager=" + ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getRestManager());
    }
}
```

Log statements should print the same instance of RestManager. In dagger id like the code maybe look like this

```
public class BaseFooFragment extends Fragment {

    @Inject BaseRestManager mBaseRestManager;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((BaseApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}

public class FooFragment extends Fragment {

    @Inject RestManager mRestManager;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide many subclass of an interface in Dagger.
Like this one:

**FirebaseDataRepository** implements **DataRepository**

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named(Scope.FIREBASE)
public DataRepository provideFirebaseData(FirebaseDataRepository repo) {
    return repo;
}
```

You can also provide another **AnyDataReposity** implements **DataRepository**

P/s: When inject you must specified which one you want to use:

```
@Named(Scope.FIREBASE) DataRepository dataRepo
```